# Aggregate rows in data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, aggregate

This is a part of the dataset (named "`ME`") I'm using:

```
   Year    Age   FemaleEXP  MaleEXP  TotalEXP  FemaleM   MaleM    TotalM 
1  1800   90-94    396.85    167.93    564.78   174.64    94.03   268.67
2  1800   95-99     42.70     12.31     55.01    27.62    13.67    41.29
3  1800 100-104      0.74      0.05      0.79     1.75     0.29     2.04
4  1800 105-109      0.00      0.03      0.00     0.01     0.00     0.00
5  1800    110+      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

I want to aggregate last 3 rows into one row, like this:

```
  Year    Age   FemaleEXP  MaleEXP  TotalEXP  FemaleM   MaleM    TotalM 
1  1800   90-94    396.85    167.93    564.78   174.64    94.03   268.67
2  1800   95-99     42.70     12.31     55.01    27.62    13.67    41.29
3  1800    100+      0.74      0.08      0.79     1.76     0.29     2.04
```

The problem is that I have more than one year (1800-2014). How can I aggregate the rows for each year? I guess I should use a for-loop but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Is `Age` character or factor? Please give `str(ME)` (edit your question)!

Comment: FYI, a loop is almost never the best option in R, because they get really slow. Instead, vectorize your code. Check out `?lapply`, and then probably a tutorial, because it won't make sense till you play with it a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table` you could do this in two simple steps (Regardless if `Age` is a factor or not)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!Age %in% c("90-94", "95-99"), Age := "100+"]
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Year, Age)]
#    Year   Age FemaleEXP MaleEXP TotalEXP FemaleM MaleM TotalM
# 1: 1800 90-94    396.85  167.93   564.78  174.64 94.03 268.67
# 2: 1800 95-99     42.70   12.31    55.01   27.62 13.67  41.29
# 3: 1800  100+      0.74    0.08     0.79    1.76  0.29   2.04
```

---

Though the more robust approach would be to pass a regex expression to the `by` statement directly (this is somewhat a modification of @akruns regex, but I'm using `gsub` directly here)

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(Year, Age = sub('^\\d{3}.*', "100+", Age))]
#    Year   Age FemaleEXP MaleEXP TotalEXP FemaleM MaleM TotalM
# 1: 1800 90-94    396.85  167.93   564.78  174.64 94.03 268.67
# 2: 1800 95-99     42.70   12.31    55.01   27.62 13.67  41.29
# 3: 1800  100+      0.74    0.08     0.79    1.76  0.29   2.04
```

Comment: FYI, It seems like you have partially edited your previous answer but it doesn't work now! Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I rolled back for now, but this was working perfectly on your data set. What does `unique(df$Age)[1:2]` gives you in your real data?

Comment: I got it: probably the problem is that I have more than 3 age groups, not only 90-94,95-99,100+ (I have 21 groups). Is it possible?

Comment: Then my solution shouldn't work either-way... Are you sure this works correctly? Probably akruns gives correct results.

Comment: Ok, see my new edit. I think this will be the best solution for your case

Answer (score 4):

If the "Age" column is `factor`, we convert it to `character` class, then change the elements in "Age" that start with 1 followed by 2 more digits to "100+", reconvert it to `factor` with `levels` specified and use `aggregate`.

```
 dfN$Age <- as.character(dfN$Age)
 dfN$Age[grep('^1\\d{2}-?', dfN$Age)] <- "100+"
 dfN$Age <- factor(dfN$Age, levels=unique(dfN$Age))
 aggregate(.~Year+Age, dfN, sum) 
 #      Year   Age FemaleEXP MaleEXP TotalEXP FemaleM MaleM TotalM
 #1 1800 90-94    396.85  167.93   564.78  174.64 94.03 268.67
 #2 1800 95-99     42.70   12.31    55.01   27.62 13.67  41.29
 #3 1800  100+      0.74    0.08     0.79    1.76  0.29   2.04
```

Comment: I borrowed some of your regex logic (and modified it a bit) if you don't mind.

Comment: @DavidArenburg No problem for me.